# How do I deal with nullable objects in JavaScript conditional statements

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have a variable that can either be set to `false` or to an object `x.y.z`.

I want to do something like this:

```
if (var1) {
  if (var1.x.y.z === 1) {
    // do stuff
  }
} else {
  // do something if var1 OR var1.x.y.z === 1 is false
}
```

I'm having trouble setting up this conditional statement without having to duplicate the else code for the outer if statement and the inner if statement.

Comment: Just `&&` the two conditions?

Comment: If `x.y.z` does not exist, I would get an `Uncaught TypeError` exception.

Comment: No, because `&&` does [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out! I hadn't heard of that before.

Answer (score 1):

Try using !!, this evaluates whatever the variable is as truthy or falsy.  Basically if var1 is not not false, thus true.  If var1 is anything but literally false then "do stuff".

Edited.. you can add the second test inline.

```
if (!!var1 && var1.x.y.z === 1) {
    // do stuff
} else {
   // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `!!` here

Comment: There is no reason not to use !! here.